# I added a column to an existing table in the database then after refreshing Entity Framework, data table (js) stopped working (server 500 error)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datatables

There is no relationship between the column I added to the table and the table attached to the datatable. I checked all the models files there are no differences. There are no warnings or errors. All the methods are working. CRUD operations are working but the single datatable is not working. There is no change in the code lines of data tables. I tried with breakpoints also the method which is providing the data to datatable is also fetching records from the table.

```
Controller method-
 public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            ThicketdbEntities db = new ThicketdbEntities();

                List<Product> products = db.Products.ToList<Product>();
                return Json(new { data = products }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }

Datatable function -
$(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable= $("#productsTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Admin/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "ProductId" },
                    { "data": "ProductName" },
                    { "data": "Price" },
                    { "data": "Description" },
                    { "data": "Dimension" },
                    { "data": "Category" },
                    {"data":"SubCategory"},
                    {
                        "data": "ProductId", "render": function (data) {
                            return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Admin")/"+data+"')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px;' onclick='Delete("+data+")'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
                        },
                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable":false,
                        "width": "150px"

                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

Product Model Class:
public partial class Product
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Product()
        {
            this.OrderDetails = new HashSet();
        }

```
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    public string Dimension { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Upload Image")]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string SubCategory { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Providing code will help identify a potential issue.  Other than that, it's all speculation right now if we try to answer.

Comment: Post edited with code

Comment: (1) try and catch the ActionResult method, (2) set catch(exception ex){ throw; }, (3) set a breakpoint in the line of throw, (4) run the app with debugging, (5) try to send a request, and finally share the received error

Comment: @AbuDawood No error caught.

Comment: please try to use the same action that fired the error during the debugging run

Comment: follow this link https://stackify.com/csharp-catch-all-exceptions/ to settle a global exception catcher. Hence, we will be able to help you. Via actual details, we can't give a hand for help. sorry

Comment: @AbuDawood Action is returning the data, as I checked with debugging. all the code is same as previous when it is working correctly but after refreshing the entity framework file datatable responding with server error.

Comment: @AbuDawood "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.OrderDetail_BEF2983E49096558A0E758AE1C31560199EF8F19907068BB230175FD9E9FEB2C'."

Comment: Okay then, wait for the answer, I am writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct the core problem, i.e. the circular object error, better to use `Newtonsoft` for serialization:

```
 string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObj /*result data object*/, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
            });
```

While, however, it is better to use IHttpActionResult in async mode

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
         List<Product> products = await db.Products.ToListAsync();

   return Ok( products /*put your object as it is, and better wrap with DTO approach*/)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Thank you for your time and patience.